# Calling a child class' method

Tags: c#, inheritance, methods, polymorphism

I am attempting to use a list which contains a series of strings using this method

```
    public  List<String> ListJobs(Job job)
    {
        List<String> ListJobs = new List<string>();

        foreach (Job curjob in Jobs)
        {


            String jobAsString = curjob.ToString();

            ListJobs.Add(jobAsString); 

        }
        return ListJobs;
  //Get the list of strings
```

My current structure is that of

JobLedger (The List in which it is all contained)

then the Job Parent class which is inherited by Visit and Pickup The problem is that in the above code, instead of using the overrided tostring method in the child class, it defaults to the parent class instead.

```
    public void NewerList()
        //No Pickup display problem is here. Liststring refers to base sting method instead of child
    {


        LstJob.Items.Clear();
        //Clears the list


        List<String> listOfVis = TheLedger.ListJobs(Thejob);
        //Get a list of strings to display in the list box


        LstJob.Items.AddRange(listOfVis.ToArray());


    }
```

I seem to have narrowed it down to This piece of code ehre, the List calls the parent Job Class, as opposed to either of the child classes

Comment: What is `Jobs`? I can only see the definition of `ListJobs`.

Comment: Where's `Jobs` declared? Why `job` isn't used? By the way: `Jobs.Select(job => job.ToString()).ToList()` does the similar, but looks shorter.

Comment: you really need to sort out your naming of variables etc.  ListJobs is a type, yet on the line beloiw you are using ListJobs as the name of a variable.  Variables should really start with a lowercase unless it is a constant, in which case all capitals words separated by _

Comment: @JonTaylor: In C# constants are usually not named following caps + underscores scheme. This is the style used in C and C++ programs. In C# constants follow the same naming rules as classes and methods: Pascal Case, i.e. upper camel case

Comment: @DanielHilgarth I stand corrected, however is this even legal code? How does one determine the difference between wanting to call a static method on the class ListJobs or calling an instance method on ListJobs variable?  I have never used C# myself, but surely naming a variable the exact same as a class is still bad?

Comment: @JonTaylor: I don't see a `ListJobs` class here. Only a `ListJobs` method. In general, the compiler can figure it out most of the time depending on the exact context, taking into account precedence rules (local variable over field etc.). If there really is an [edge case](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-353104) where it can't figure it out additional qualification like a namespace will make it clear.

Answer (score 1):

Try type casting the object you are getting to the class which contains the function you want to be used.

Comment: @DGibbs as you can see I do not have required reputation to leave a comment on posts that I have not made. I'm new here

Comment: Welcome to SO! Consider reading through [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). If you can't provide a correct answer then you should not answer at all.

Comment: I was trying to go with “try this instead” way of giving an answer.
I thought that doing what my answer told would help. But I agree that I was not sure that my answer would be correct.

Comment: I disagree with DGibbs, if you have anything to contribute then you should, when you have the reputation to post a comment then that is what this should be

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you really *override* `ToString`.

What you are describing sounds more like you are *shadowing* it in the derived classes.

`override` (What you want):

```
public override string ToString()
{
    // ...
}
```

*shadow* (What I think you have):

```
public string ToString()
{
    // ...
}

// or:

public new string ToString()
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I've got the tostring Methods overridden in every case. the main issue is that the listjobs method is calling the Tostring in the parent Job Class as opposed to the intended child class

Comment: @DenisAllan: But that's exactly what polymorphism is supposed to work out for you. Please show some code that let's us reproduce your problem.

Comment: 'public void NewerList()
            //No Pickup display problem is here. Liststring refers to base sting method instead of child
        {


            LstJob.Items.Clear();
            //Clears the list



            List<String> listOfVis = TheLedger.ListJobs(Thejob);
            //Get a list of strings to display in the list box


            LstJob.Items.AddRange(listOfVis.ToArray());           
        }' 

This is the code i have worked it down to, the 'List<string>' method calls to the base 'tostring()' in the parent 'job' class. Sorry if my formatting here is bad.

Comment: @DenisAllan: Update your question with this info please.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `override` before the overrided method.

Comment: Good. Just so you know: I didn't downvote, so I can't remove the -1 you already got.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: It's no problem. If this is not the correct answer, I will remove it after some minutes :)